# Is there a native,relaxed PHP 8.1 function to return the value for the key of an associative array in a way similar to PHP7.4?

Tags: php, regression, compatibility

Consider this *"broken"* code which only produces a notice in PHP 7.4 but now produces an error in PHP 8.1:

*error_code:2:Trying to access array offset on value of type bool:*

```
$arrStuff=[];
$arrSubStuff=end($arrStuff); // Sets $arrSubStuff to false
var_dump($arrSubStuff["thing"]); // Displays NULL
```

I need a (preferably native) function which I have fictitiously named "get_array_value" and which would do something like this:

```
$arrStuff=[];
$arrSubStuff=end($arrStuff); // Sets $arrSubStuff to false
var_dump(get_array_value($arrSubStuff,"thing")); // Displays NULL
```

This is so that I can avoid the following code bloat which would otherwise be necessary when processing "naughty" data which comes in from the wild and could contain ANY data type.
The ideal would be that it would emulate early PHP behaviour (a nod to Perl as a text processing language) and play nicely with any unexpected data type, leaning on the programmer rather than the unnuanced, blunt instrument, runtime environment to check for stupidity.

Does such a native function exist in PHP ? Please tell me it's a case of RTFM ! :-)

```
$arrStuff=[];
$arrSubStuff=end($arrStuff); // Sets $arrSubStuff to false

//Check if arrSubStuff is an array before checking array_key_exists otherwise we get error: Argument #2 ($array) must be of type array, bool given
if (is_array($arrSubStuff)){
  // Check the array key exists otherwise we get PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "thing"
  if (array_key_exists("thing",$arrSubStuff)){
    var_dump($arrSubStuff["thing"]);
  } else {
    var_dump(null);
  }
} else {
 var_dump(null);
}
```

I'd rather not have to use a function to do it but if that's what is required in the name of "progress" then so be it. No, staying on an earlier PHP version is not an option: #SecurityUpgrades.

#RegressionTesting #UpgradeMaintenanceCosts

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP non-falsy null coalesce operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40607690/php-non-falsy-null-coalesce-operator)

Comment: @MarkusZeller Yes, that works. Thank you. It's going to be a hell of a faff to implement in a large codebase.

Comment: I did not use it, yet, but you may give a try to this: https://getrector.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily there's no such native function, but you can use null coalescing operator (`??`) instead:

```php
$arrStuff=[];
$arrSubStuff = end($arrStuff);
var_dump($arrSubStuff['foo'] ?? null);
```

would give expected

```bash
NULL
```

And you can always wrap this into own method/function if needed.

Comment: Yes, that works. Thank you.  It's going to be a hell of a faff to implement in a large project.

Comment: No worse that replacing with native function. But hey, at the end of the day your code will be better :)

Comment: Indeed, no worse than replacing with a native function. Not convinced the code is any better: Just more to worry about. Thank you